# Object Instantiation - Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is a common question, but i am not clear on the answers I found on the internet or StackOverflow.

When we instantiate an object in selenium `WebDriver` (say selenium webdriver and Java), we generally write (as a normal practice),

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Or use any other implementation of `WebDriver` interface (Chrome, IE, Safari, `AndroidDriver`, etc).

Why we don't use something like below

```
FirefoxDriver fx = new FirefoxDriver();
```

WebDriver being an interface, only the methods of `WebDriver` that are implemented by the specific browser implementation class would be accessible. The methods of the, say `FireFoxDriver`, that are not in `WebDriver` interface would not be accessible by the reference.

Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the interface `WebDriver` instead of the implementation. This is a general technique named:

> code/programming to the interface

so if in the future you ever need to switch to a different driver, let's say switch from `ChromeDriver` to `FirefoxDriver` your code will remain intact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i guess its one of the OO principles. Searched on google for more examples. Got more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to call the **WebDriver** as it contains all the methods you need for testing.

Here is the example:

protected static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

or

protected static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Sorry, but my doubt is still unclear. We create a reference to WebDriver and Object of the implementation class. Using the WebDriver reference, we ultimately use the methods of implementation classes (thanks to polymorphism). The methods in WebDriver interface are implemented in different browser implementation classes which are used at the end. So ultimately, both the statements make me use of the methods in implementation classes. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.